# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) Substring Error in CREATE TABLE command

Tags: mysql, substring

I am trying to convert from SQL Server to MySQL. I have an issue converting the SQL Server Substring function call:

`[Code] AS (substring([Num],(3),(3))),`

to MySQL format:

`SELECT SUBSTRING(Num,3,3),`

When I ran it at the MySQL Command Line Client, I got this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELEC T SUBSTRING(Num,3,3),
>           PRIMARY KEY(`Num`,`ImageNum`) )' at line 28

Comment: show the complete query. I'm not sure why `PRIMARY  KEY` and `SELECT` are in the same query. Are you after the [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) SQL form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add a generated column, for which in MySQL the syntax would be:

```
Code VARCHAR(3) AS (SUBSTRING(Num, 3, 3))
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is the manual page for generated columns in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thanks Nick! It works! Now I know how to add a generated column in MySQL.